# crontab to wake osx from sleep

Tags: macos, script, cron

I have a crontab which will launch a certain program early in the morning (after I have gone to sleep) and close it again later in the morning (before I wake up). But my iMac will not execute the crontab script while it is asleep.

I see there is some preferences to wake the machine up and make it sleep again at a specified time, but is there a way to do this using the crontab?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`cron` doesn't execute while the computer is asleep, so there's no way for you to have a crontab entry to wake the computer. That said you can schedule the computer to wake just a minute or two before your cron task in Preferences >> Energy Saver >> Schedule.

It's also worth pointing out that since Tiger, Apple has moved most scheduled jobs from `cron` and scripts like `init.rc` to the `launchd` process. It provides more detailed (but cumbersome, I think) means of control (through several plist files). It will also automatically run tasks missed because the computer was sleeping when it awakens. Take a look at Apple's [Scheduling Timed Jobs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) page.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Great answer, but can you wake it when the laptop is closed?

Answer (score 10):

Another way to schedule waking up from sleep is to use pmset:

```
sudo pmset repeat wakeorpoweron MTWRFSU 03:45:00
```

launchd cannot wake a computer from sleep, but it does run jobs scheduled during sleep after waking up. If others search for how to do that, you can for example save this plist as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/some.label.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>some.label</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>say</string>
    <string>a</string>
  </array>
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>23</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>59</integer>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/some.label.plist`.

Answer (score 4):

You can schedule your Macintosh to wake up in the Energy Saver preference panel.  See the Schedule button.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [Anacron](http://members.cox.net/18james/anacron-tiger.html)

> Anacron runs the periodic daily,
>   weekly and monthly tasks on your Mac
>   even if the machine (a laptop, for
>   example) spends much of its time
>   asleep or switched-off. **Anacron
>   silently checks when you reboot and
>   every sixty minutes while the computer
>   is running to see if the various
>   periodic scripts are overdue, and runs
>   them if necessary.** The advantage of
>   Anacron over many other solutions to
>   this issue is that it runs as a proper
>   Unix background process, requires no
>   user intervention, and uses the
>   regular periodic scripts.

Another applicaiton that might do the trick is [Awaken](http://embraceware.com/awaken/)

Comment: For future readers, it seems Anacron is not supported in Mac https://stackoverflow.com/a/42654433/3090068

Answer (score 1):

cron will not run while OSX is in sleep mode.

You may want to look into [cronwake](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fhomepage.mac.com%2Fnand%2Fmacosx%2Fcronwake.html&sl=auto&tl=en&history_state0=) (must run through google translate as the site is japanese I believe) and [anacron](http://members.cox.net/18james/anacron-tiger.html), or you can just use the `Energy Saver` application to schedule a wake time to run the script, then put it back to sleep.